# Use authentication against encrypted password

Tags: php, authentication, encryption, passwords, zend-framework2

I have the password encrypted in dataBase by *zend2*'s **BlockCipher**:

```
 public function cipher($incKey, $password) {

        $cipher = BlockCipher::factory ( 'mcrypt', array (
                'algorithm' => 'aes'
        ));

        $cipher->setKey ( $incKey );
        $text = $password;

        $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt ( $text );

        echo "Encrypted text: $encrypted \n";
        return $encrypted;

    }
```

Now I need to authenticate the user's password when logging in:

```
$cipher = new Cipher();

$ciphered_password = $cipher->cipher($incKey, $data['usr_password']);

$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,
        'users', 
        'email',
        'password', 
        "CONCAT('$ciphered_password') AND state= 1"
        );
```

But doesn't pass the authentication;

with code: **FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID**

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encryption mode `Blockcipher::factory` uses is not deterministic. [It uses CBC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.crypt.block-cipher.html) which is initialized with a random IV and thus every ciphertext (encrypted plaintext) looks differently and pseudorandom. You should use password *hashing* instead. [This page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.crypt.password.html) seems to be the appropriate resource for it in zend. Over at security.se you can find some [background knowledge to password storage](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Comment: What matters me is the part how to add the CONCAT('$ciphered_password') to work

Comment: @GingerHead: I don't see how that would be possible. Essentially what you are doing is this `$password=$data['usr_password']; $ciphered_password=getRandom(); compareAgainstDatabase($ciphered_password)`.

Comment: what about if I need to do codification only with base 64?

Comment: @GingerHead, are asking how you can replace the encryption with base64 encoding? What problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to provide a login for users which can choose their own password and you later need to verify that they indeed supply the correct password again? Then [password hashing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) really is right way to go. It avoids a lot of problems with illegal characters in the passwords, too long passwords for you database column, etc. and is the first and easiest security enhancement against the problems of database breaches.

Comment: it encodes the password in base 64 before saving in the DB?